# Remove code duplication from RLE pattern, without resorting to Haskell?

Tags: python, haskell, run-length-encoding

The RLE (run length encoding) pattern seems to come up a lot in my work.

The essence of it is that you are outputting a reduction of the elements encountered since the last 'break' each time that you see a 'break' *or* you reach the end of the input.

(In actual RLE, the 'break' is just this character not matching the last character, but in the real world it's usually a little more complex, but still a function of the current and last elements.)

I want to remove the duplicate `last_val != None:  rle.append((last_val, count))` condition and action which occur both in the loop and at the end.

The issues are:

1. replacing them with function calls results in more code, not less.
2. keeping it in imperative style (in Haskell, for example, the problem just evapourates).

The imperative Python code is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

data = "abbbccac"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  rle = []
  last_val = None
  count = 0;

  for val in data:
    if val != last_val and last_val != None:
      rle.append((last_val, count))
      count = 1
    else:
      count += 1
    last_val = val
  if last_val != None:
    rle.append((last_val, count))

  print rle
```

P.S. Trivially solvable in functional languages:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
import Data.List (group)

dat = "abbbccac"

rle :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
rle arr = map (\g -> (head g, length g)) $ group arr

main :: IO ()
main = print $ rle dat
```

Comment: For what it's worth, in Haskell you just need `rle = map (head &&& length) . group`.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe - thanks, I didn't know about the &&& operator.  Point-free style still looks a lot less maintainable than 'normal' Haskell.

Comment: The `&&&` function (from `Control.Arrow`) is quite popular, so most Haskell programmers will recognize it. I think it's quite narrative too, I read `map (head &&& length)` as "map the functions `head` and `length` on...". I like how `&&&` corresponds to "and".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more imperative form. You can eliminate your duplicate code by adding or chaining to a throwaway sentinel that will never match any of your list elements, forcing an end-of-sequence pass through your "this-not-equal-last" code:

```
from itertools import chain

def rle(seq):
    ret = []
    sentinel = object()
    enum = enumerate(chain(seq,[sentinel]))
    start,last = next(enum)
    for i,c in enum:
        if c != last:
            ret.append((last,i-start))
            start,last = i,c
    return ret
```

This even gracefully handles the case where the input seq is empty, and the input can be any sequence, iterator, or generator, not just a string.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, though I really see it as an acknowledgement that for these sorts of problems FP (in whatever language) is far more useful than imperative style.  My question was posed to see if I missed an obvious, elegant solution in imperative style; I don't think I did.

Comment: I thought that chaining with the sentinel so that you didn't have to duplicate your `ret.append` code bordered on elegance.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially solvable using the Python "batteries included":

```
>>> data = "abbbccac"
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> ilen = lambda gen : sum(1 for x in gen)
>>> print [(ch, ilen(ich)) for ch,ich in groupby(data)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ('a', 1), ('c', 1)]
```

`groupby` returns an iterator of 2-tuples. The first is the value that represents the next group, and the second is an iterator you can use to iterate over the items in the group. You just want the length of the group, but you can't take the length directly, so I added the simple `ilen` lambda function to compute the length for an iterator.

Comment: Darn .. can't decide if I like the efficiency of the lambda or my brevity of the list :)

Comment: The lambda itself does not add any efficiency, but I think it is a bit more readable. The only efficiency in my answer over yours is the use of sum instead of list - your list creates temporary lists and my sum expression just walks the iterator of the items. If you just inline `sum(1 for gg in g)` in place of `len(list(g))` you'll get that same efficiency. The only time you gain efficiency with passing functions to methods like groupby, sort, map, filter, etc. is if you pass a C-implemented builtin like itemgetter - Python functions and lambdas all get called without any optimization.

Comment: Erm .. that's what I meant ... the use of lambda enables you to walk the iterator .. hence more memory efficient if hitting large blocks :)

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I've done some timings - and to my great surprise it turns out that using list is lot faster - go figure :)

Comment: @MariaZverina - I could not replicate your tests. I get `0.090725268883
0.188734752626
0.0886793186812
0.0129811873076
0.102645998342
11.6004055431`, where the last 2 values are run against your chunk blocks string * 1000.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire and Karl Knectel Great answers, but I had specifically asked "keeping it in imperative style", as the problem is trivial if approached from an FP view.  I should have written the question in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Simple if I understood it right ...

```
from itertools import groupby

data = "abbbccac"

print [(k, len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(data)]
```

Wow - got very surprising results comparing Paul's very similar function to mine. It turns out the loading the list is 10-100 times faster. Even more surprising is the that the list implementation has bigger advantage as the blocks get larger.

I guess this is why I ♥ Python - it makes the terse expression work better - even if it sometimes seems like magic.

Check the data for yourself:

```
from itertools import groupby
from timeit import Timer

data = "abbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccac" 

def rle_walk(gen):
    ilen = lambda gen : sum(1 for x in gen)
    return [(ch, ilen(ich)) for ch,ich in groupby(data)]

def rle_list(data):
    return [(k, len(list(g))) for k,g in groupby(data)]

# randomy data
t = Timer('rle_walk("abbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccac")', "from __main__ import rle_walk; gc.enable()")
print t.timeit(1000)

t = Timer('rle_list("abbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccacabbbccac")', "from __main__ import rle_list; gc.enable()")
print t.timeit(1000)

# chunky blocks
t = Timer('rle_walk("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc")', "from __main__ import rle_walk; gc.enable()")
print t.timeit(1000)

t = Timer('rle_list("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc")', "from __main__ import rle_list; gc.enable()")
print t.timeit(1000)
```

Gives me results of (smaller is better):

```
1.42423391342    # lambda and walk - small blocks
0.145968914032   # make list - small blocks
1.41816806793    # lambda and walk - large blocks
0.0165541172028  # make list - large blocks
```

Comment: `Simple if I understood it right` made me snicker. Famous last words. :-)

Comment: Paul McGuire's solution is more efficient as he doesn't end up loading the list into memory ... but if you only have small length of run encoded data the brevity of list expression might be ok ...

Comment: Interesting! I also tried a version in which I inlined the sum expression as I suggested to you earlier, like this: `def rle_walk_inline(gen): 
    return [(ch, sum(1 for x in ich)) for ch,ich in groupby(data)]` and there is a consistent 15-20% reduction in time (by saving the overhead of the function call to the lambda). Also, try rerunning your tests with a really long string - take your chunky blocks test and multiply the string by 1000. My tests show that using sum over the iterator is pretty consistent across all the tests - for a long string, `len(list(g))` is about 1000X slower.

Comment: I also don't see the 100X slower behavior for rle_walk when I run your tests.  I get `0.090725268883
0.188734752626
0.0886793186812
0.0129811873076
0.102645998342
11.6004055431`, where the last 2 values are for your chunky blocks string * 1000.

Comment: Good answer, but I had specifically asked "keeping it in imperative style", as the problem is trivial if approached from an FP view.  I should have written the original question in Java to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least get rid of the else clause if you use `enumerate` to keep track of how many values you've seen and store last_val and last_index (or (last_val, last_index) as a tuple).  E.g.

```
last_index = 0
last_val = None

for index, val in enumerate(data):
    if val != last_val and last_val is not None:
        rle.append((last_val, index - last_index + 1))
        last_val = val
        last_index = index
    last_val = val
if last_val is not None:
    rle.append((last_val, index - last_index + 1))
```

you can also start the enumerate at any point and it'll count up (so you could initialize it with `enumerate(data, last_index)`. It looks like you want the count to start at 1, which is why I added the `+ 1` part.

Enumerate just counts how many elements have been produced from the iterator, doesn't matter the type.

Comment: Note that as `enumerate(G)` is equal to `izip(count(), (G))`, you could get rid of the `+ 1` by using `izip(count(1), (G))` instead. (`izip` and `count` are from the `itertools` module)

Comment: This leaves out the last group.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I noticed that right after I posted it and thought I'd edited it, weird. Still, good eye!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the groupby solution but the most convenient way to write an imperative solution is often as a generator:

```
data = "abbbccac"

def rle(xs):
    def g():
        last = object()
        n = 0
        for x in xs:
            if x != last:
                yield last,n
                last = x
                n = 0
            n += 1
    return list(g())[1:]

print rle(data)
```